# KivyMD widgets displaying at the bottom of page in MDBoxLayout

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

KivyMD widgets are displayed at the bottom when using MDBoxLayout. I remember two MDTextField widgets and one MDRaisedButton, but they are located at the bottom. When using Kivy without KivyMD, there is no such problem. Here is my code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager

KV = """
ScreenManager:
    MDScreen:
        name: "main"
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            MDTextField:
                hint_text: "User ID"
                hint_size: 36
                font_size: 36
            MDTextField:
                hint_text: "Message"
                hint_size: 36
                font_size: 36
            MDRaisedButton:
                text: "START"
                font_size: 36
                increment_width: 100
"""

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)
        
    def on_start(self):
        self.root.current = "main"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Result:
[Result of run this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtS1X.jpg)

I tried to replace MDBoxLayout to BoxLayout and MDScreen to Screen, but this not helped.

Comment: That's because you are using `MDBoxLayout` and here all of its children has fixed height (or size) with default position (0, 0). Try using `FloatLayout` alongwith `pos_hint`.

Comment: @ApuCoder Thank you, I already solved the problem but I will remember this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved a problem. I was need to add this to MDBoxLayout:

```
pos_hint: {"top": 1}
adaptive_height: True
```

And result code is:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager

KV = """
ScreenManager:
    MDScreen:
        name: "main"
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            pos_hint: {"top": 1}
            adaptive_height: True
            MDTextField:
                hint_text: "User ID"
                hint_size: 36
                font_size: 36
            MDTextField:
                hint_text: "Message"
                hint_size: 36
                font_size: 36
            MDRaisedButton:
                text: "START"
                font_size: 36
                increment_width: 100
"""

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)
        
    def on_start(self):
        self.root.current = "main"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

**Thanks KivyMD community in KivyMD's Discord!**